# Has support for non-UEFI/non-I386 been dropped?

Tags: 12.04, installation, kubuntu, uefi

I attempted to install the 13.04 distribution using the AMD iso, since my system uses an AMD64 cpu architecture. After numerous attempts, all failing with "Grub Installation Failed.", I gave up.

After doing some research I came to the conclusion that the AMD iso does not work with a non-UEFI. Can anyone confirm this conclusion?

In the interim I will be returning to version 10.04 while I research other distributions. I really like the kubuntu distributions and I hope that there is some way of making it work. The following are the details of my system:

- CPU Type: AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HDGraphics
- CPU Speed: 1.40 GHz
- HDD Model Name: ST9500325AS
- ATAPI Model Name: HL-DT-STDVRAM GT32N
- System BIOS Version: V1.09
- VGA BIOS Version: BK-ATI VER012.043.000.014.040915
- FBC Version: 1.07
- Product Name: Aspire 5560
- Manufacturer Name: Acer

Comment: I've removed large parts of your question as they seem to be completely irrelevant to your actual question. Please keep personal frustrations and experiences about other distribution out of your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> AMD iso does not work with a non-UEFI. Can anyone confirm this conclusion?

No, all Ubuntu images work fine with general BIOS systems. Really. As you don't include any reference to that "research", I don't see how you come to that conclusion.

And while the actual i368 architecture isn't supported anymore, the i686 architecture and up still is (despite keeping the i386 name), next to x86_64 (also referred to as amd64 and this has nothing to do with AMD, just the support for the amd64 instruction set).

From the [Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/hardware-supported.html):

> However, Ubuntu precise will not run on i586 or earlier processors. Despite the architecture name "i386", support for actual 80386 processors (and their clones) was dropped with the Sarge (r3.1) release of Debian[2]. (No version of Linux has ever supported the 286 or earlier chips in the series.) Support for i586 and lower processors, as well as for i686 processors without the cmov instruction, was dropped in Ubuntu 10.10. Most i686 and later processors are still supported[3].